# android:Store data in Sqlite from List<HashMap>

Tags: java, android, sqlite, hashmap

In my project there is a list of category and every category has multiple item .I want to store these category with its multiple items.My question is can i store it in sqlite and i want retrieve it in recycle view.

[![In the screenshot every category is given with the selection number.i want to insert it with category with its multiple items and also want to show as given in screenshots][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WaKm.png `public class ViewAllAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private ArrayList<StringMenuListBean> dataList;
private Context mContext;
private TextView itemText;
private List<String> itemList;

public ViewAllAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<StringMenuListBean> dataList) {
    this.dataList = dataList;
    this.mContext = context;
}


@Override
public ItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rowitem_viewall, null);
    v.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    ));
    ItemRowHolder mh = new ItemRowHolder(v, mContext);
    return mh;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemRowHolder itemRowHolder, int position) {

    itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    final StringMenuListBean model = dataList.get(position);
    String str = model.getName();
    String category = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("-"));
    String item = str.substring(str.indexOf("-") + 1, str.length());
    itemList.add(item);

    itemRowHolder.linear.removeAllViews();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    llp.setMargins(50, 0, 0, 0); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

    Log.e("category", category);
    Log.e("remainder", item);
    itemRowHolder.tv_category_item.setText(category + " :");

    for (int k = 0; k < itemList.size(); k++) {

        itemText = new TextView(mContext);
        itemText.setText((position + 1) + " ." + item);
        itemText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#43A047"));
        itemText.setLayoutParams(llp);
        itemRowHolder.linear.addView(itemText);

    }


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != dataList ? dataList.size() : 0);
}


public class ItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView tv_category_item;
    protected LinearLayout linear;


    public ItemRowHolder(View view, final Context mContextv) {
        super(view);

        tv_category_item = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_category_item);
        linear = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear);
    }

}
```

}

`here is my Activity`public class ViewAllActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
RecyclerView viewall_recycleview;
ViewAllAdapter viewallAdapter;
TextView tv_ID;
TextView tv_PACKID;
TextView tv_PACKAGENAME;
TextView tv_USERID;
TextView tv_USER_NAME;
TextView tv_CATID;
TextView tv_CATNAME;
TextView tv_MENUITEMS;
TextView tv_MEMBER;
TextView tv_DATE;
TextView tv_TIME;
TextView tv_TOTAL_PRICE;
TextView tv_ORDER_TYPE;
TextView tv_DISCOUNT;
TextView tv_CITY;
TextView tv_PROMOCODE;
TextView tv_PAYMENT_STATUS;
TextView tv_PRICE;
TextView tv_MENUID;
TextView tv_SUBPACKAGENAME;
TextView tv_CURRENT_DATE;
Button btn_download;

MenuDetailBean menuDetailBean;
Bundle activitybundle;
String subpackage_id, pack_id;
String menuitem;
ArrayList<StringMenuListBean> stringMenuList;
StringMenuListBean stringMenu;
List<String> menulist;
List<String> arraylist1;
File imagePath;
RecyclerView rcyView_mymenu;

Bitmap bitmap;
View view;
ByteArrayOutputStream bytearrayoutputstream;
File file;
FileOutputStream fileoutputstream;
boolean boolean_save;
LinearLayout ll_linear;


MenuAdapter menuAdapter;

public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewall);

    init();
    setTextAndList();
    btn_download.setOnClickListener(this);


}

private void init() {
    activitybundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    pack_id = activitybundle.getString("pack_id");
    subpackage_id = activitybundle.getString("sub_package_id");
```

//        Log.e("subpackage_id",subpackage_id);

```
    bytearrayoutputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


    rcyView_mymenu = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rcyView_mymenu);
    rcyView_mymenu.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    tv_SUBPACKAGENAME = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_SUBPACKAGENAME);
    tv_PRICE = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_PRICE);
    tv_TOTAL_PRICE = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_TOTAL_PRICE);
    tv_DATE = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_DATE);
    tv_TIME = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_TIME);
    tv_MEMBER = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_MEMBER);
    tv_ORDER_TYPE = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_ORDER_TYPE);
    btn_download = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_download);
    ll_linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_linear);


}

private void setTextAndList() {
    menuDetailBean = DbUtils.getMenuDetail(getApplicationContext(), pack_id);

    tv_SUBPACKAGENAME.setText(menuDetailBean.getSUBPACKAGE_NAME());
    tv_PRICE.setText(menuDetailBean.getPRICE() + "/-");
    tv_TOTAL_PRICE.setText(menuDetailBean.getTOTAL_PRICE() + "Rs.");
    tv_DATE.setText(menuDetailBean.getDATE());
    tv_TIME.setText(menuDetailBean.getTIME());
    tv_MEMBER.setText(menuDetailBean.getMEMBER());
    tv_ORDER_TYPE.setText(menuDetailBean.getORDER_TYPE());

    menuitem = menuDetailBean.getMENUITEMS();
    menulist = Arrays.asList(menuitem.split(","));
    Log.e("meuitem", "" + menulist.size());
    stringMenuList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < menulist.size(); i++) {
        StringMenuListBean stringMenu = new StringMenuListBean();
        stringMenu.setName(menulist.get(i));
        stringMenuList.add(stringMenu);
    }

    viewallAdapter = new ViewAllAdapter(getApplication(), stringMenuList);
    rcyView_mymenu.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rcyView_mymenu.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    rcyView_mymenu.setAdapter(viewallAdapter);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_download:

            Bitmap bitmap1 = loadBitmapFromView(ll_linear, ll_linear.getWidth(), ll_linear.getHeight());
            saveBitmap(bitmap1);

            break;

    }

}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

    File imagePath = new File("/sdcard/screenshotdemo.jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), imagePath.getAbsolutePath() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        boolean_save = true;

        btn_download.setText("Check image");

        Log.e("ImageSave", "Saveimage");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

}

 `this is my Activity and below is my Database Utility code in which i saved all cart item . i want every added item is shown in different activity with its whole information.`public class DbUtils {

```
public static void saveCart(Context context, CartItemBean data) {
    ContentValues value = new ContentValues();


    // for (CartItemBean data : data1) {
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_PACKID, data.getCOLUMN_PACKID());
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_PACKAGENAME, data.getCOLUMN_PACKAGENAME());
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_SUBPACKAGEID, data.getCOLUMN_SUBPACKAGE_ID());
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_SUBPACKAGENAME, data.getCOLUMN_SUBPACKAGE_NAME());
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_USERID, data.getCOLUMN_USERID());
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_USER_NAME, data.getCOLUMN_USER_NAME());
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_CATID, data.getCOLUMN_CATID());
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_CATNAME, data.getCOLUMN_CATNAME());
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_MENUITEMS, data.getCOLUMN_MENUITEMS());
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_MENUID, data.getCOLUMN_MENUID());
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_MEMBER, data.getCOLUMN_MEMBER());
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_DATE, data.getCOLUMN_DATE());
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_TIME, data.getCOLUMN_TIME());
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_TOTAL_PRICE, data.getCOLUMN_TOTAL_PRICE());
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_ORDER_TYPE, data.getCOLUMN_ORDER_TYPE());
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_DISCOUNT, data.getCOLUMN_DISCOUNT());
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_CITY, data.getCOLUMN_CITY());
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_CURRENTDATE, data.getCOLUMN_CURRENT_DATE());
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_PRICE, data.getCOLUMN_PRICE());
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_PROMOCODE, data.getCOLUMN_PROMOCODE());
    value.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_PAYMENT_STATUS, data.getCOLUMN_PAYMENT_STATUS());
    DbAccesser.getInstance(context).insertIntoTable(value,
            DbConstants.TABLE_CART);
    // }
}

// get product list
public static ArrayList<CartItemBean> getCartItems(Context context) {
    ArrayList<CartItemBean> offlineDataList = new ArrayList<CartItemBean>();
    Cursor cursor = DbAccesser.getInstance(context).query(DbConstants.TABLE_CART, null, null,
            null, null, null, null);


    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            CartItemBean data = new CartItemBean();

            data.setCOLUMN_ID((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_ID))));
            data.setCOLUMN_CATID((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_CATID))));
            data.setCOLUMN_PAYMENT_STATUS((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_PAYMENT_STATUS))));
            data.setCOLUMN_USER_NAME(((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_USER_NAME)))));
            data.setCOLUMN_USERID((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_USERID))));
            data.setCOLUMN_PACKAGENAME((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_PACKAGENAME))));
            data.setCOLUMN_CATNAME((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_CATNAME))));
            data.setCOLUMN_CITY((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_CITY))));
            data.setCOLUMN_CURRENT_DATE((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_CURRENTDATE))));
            data.setCOLUMN_DATE((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_DATE))));
            data.setCOLUMN_DISCOUNT(((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_DISCOUNT)))));
            data.setCOLUMN_MEMBER((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_MEMBER))));
            data.setCOLUMN_MENUITEMS((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_MENUITEMS))));
            data.setCOLUMN_ORDER_TYPE((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_ORDER_TYPE))));
            data.setCOLUMN_PACKID((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_PACKID))));
            data.setCOLUMN_PROMOCODE((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_PROMOCODE))));
            data.setCOLUMN_TIME(((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_TIME)))));
            data.setCOLUMN_PRICE(((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_PRICE)))));
            data.setCOLUMN_MENUID(((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_MENUID)))));
            data.setCOLUMN_TOTAL_PRICE(((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_TOTAL_PRICE)))));
            data.setCOLUMN_SUBPACKAGE_ID(((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_SUBPACKAGEID)))));
            data.setCOLUMN_SUBPACKAGE_NAME(((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_SUBPACKAGENAME)))));


            offlineDataList.add(data);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return offlineDataList;
}


public static MenuDetailBean getMenuDetail(Context context, String packId) {

    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + DbConstants.TABLE_CART + " WHERE "
            + DbConstants.COLUMN_PACKID + " = " + packId;


    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c != null)
        c.moveToFirst();

    MenuDetailBean menuDetailBean = new MenuDetailBean();
    menuDetailBean.setTIME(((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_TIME)))));
    menuDetailBean.setDATE(((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_DATE)))));
    menuDetailBean.setSUBPACKAGE_NAME(((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_SUBPACKAGENAME)))));
    menuDetailBean.setPRICE(((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_PRICE)))));
    menuDetailBean.setTOTAL_PRICE(((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_TOTAL_PRICE)))));
    menuDetailBean.setMEMBER(((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_MEMBER)))));
    menuDetailBean.setORDER_TYPE(((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_ORDER_TYPE)))));
    menuDetailBean.setMENUITEMS(((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_MENUITEMS)))));
    menuDetailBean.setCURRENT_DATE(((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbConstants.COLUMN_CURRENTDATE)))));
    return menuDetailBean;
}


public static int deteteTableData(Context context, String tableName) {
    int status = 0;
    status = DbAccesser.getInstance(context).deleteTable(tableName);

    return status;
}


public static void deleteOrderAfterTEnDays(Context context) {
    Cursor cursor = DbAccesser.getInstance(context).raw_query("delete from new_order where current_datetime < default current_timestamp - INTERVAL 10 DAY", null);
    Log.e("CURSOR", "" + cursor);
}


// get bill by particular date and outletId
public static CartItemBean getOrderBillByOutlet(Context context, CartItemBean bean) {
    CartItemBean cartItemBean = new CartItemBean();

    String[] params = new String[]{bean.getCOLUMN_PACKID(), bean.getCOLUMN_MEMBER(), bean.getCOLUMN_DATE(), bean.getCOLUMN_TIME()};

    Cursor cursor = DbAccesser.getInstance(context).raw_query("select column_id,name,SUM(order_billing) from cart where order_date=? AND outlets_id=?", params);


    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        }

    }
    return cartItemBean;

}

public static void updateRetailerList(Context context, CartItemBean cartItemBean) {


    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    values.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_MEMBER, cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_MEMBER());
    values.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_DATE, cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_DATE());
    values.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_TIME, cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_TIME());
    values.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_TIME, cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_ORDER_TYPE());
    values.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_TIME, cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_TOTAL_PRICE());
    values.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_TIME, cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_ORDER_TYPE());
    values.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_TIME, cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_TOTAL_PRICE());
    values.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_SUBPACKAGEID, cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_SUBPACKAGE_ID());
    values.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_SUBPACKAGENAME, cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_SUBPACKAGE_NAME());
    values.put(DbConstants.COLUMN_CURRENTDATE, cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_CURRENT_DATE());


    String sql2 = "UPDATE " + DbConstants.TABLE_CART + " SET " +
            DbConstants.COLUMN_MEMBER + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_MEMBER() + "', "
            + DbConstants.COLUMN_DATE + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_DATE() + "', "
            + DbConstants.COLUMN_TIME + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_TIME() + "', "
            + DbConstants.COLUMN_SUBPACKAGEID + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_SUBPACKAGE_ID() + "', "
            + DbConstants.COLUMN_SUBPACKAGENAME + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_SUBPACKAGE_NAME() + "', "
            + DbConstants.COLUMN_CURRENTDATE + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_CURRENT_DATE() + "', "
            + DbConstants.COLUMN_TOTAL_PRICE + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_TOTAL_PRICE() + "' "

            + " WHERE " +
            DbConstants.COLUMN_PACKID + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_PACKID() + "' AND "
            + DbConstants.COLUMN_USERID + " = '" + cartItemBean.getCOLUMN_USERID() + "'";

    database.execSQL(sql2);
    Log.e("UPDATE", sql2);

}

public static void deleteCartItem(Context context, String packId, String userId) {
    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    database.delete(DbConstants.TABLE_CART, DbConstants.COLUMN_PACKID + "=? AND "+ DbConstants.COLUMN_USERID + "=?", new String[]{packId, userId});
    database.close();

}`
```

Comment: Do you have tried anything? You could for example have a table of category names, and a table of potential item names, with the category they belong to. When you have that, provide a `.dump` of that database, for the purpose of making something of a [mcve]. Then make an attempt of making a table which lists the associations of category and item. If that does not satisfy you, decribe how so. Then you might find help with solving that specific problem.

Comment: yes i tried it i converted whole items in string stream separated by comma and all item heading also attached with dash - like this SOUP-Tomato Soup,sweet Corn,Namkeen-kachori,aloo bade,. like this but problem is that i want to split that again in previous form ,i tried it some how i did it but still one problem is arising. my code breaks it like this Namkeen 1 kachori    Namkeen 2 aloo bade every item in next line. in this i want if i choose two item from Namkeen than it should look like that Namkeen has two item @Yunnosch , but it is repeating Namkeen every Namkeen is taken single item.

Comment: So you have code, show it.

Comment: Please also add the pure SQLite code which you get from a `.dump` via commandline tool. That makes testing and improving your code so much easier.

Comment: If there is any other useful additional information in your comment (lack of formatting makes it so hard to read), please edit your question to also incorporate that.

Comment: Your last edit killed the "M" of MCVE ([mcve]). Sorry for confusing you, that is not what I meant by "pure SQLite code which you get from a `.dump` via commandline tool". I would like to be able to easily create a suitable toy database.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you look at the new Room persistence library in the Android Components library. Removes any complex sql queries

Comment: @cricket_007 You probably addressed OP. But I am interested, too (and I am non-android, non-java; just curious). Could you link?

Comment: @Yunn https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can associate multiple items to each category, by creating a table with entries which each reflect an association.

For example, assuming you have a toy database like quoted at the end of this answer (see "MCVE foundation").

Create the table and add a few associations:

```
create table associations (id int, iid int);
insert into associations values (1, 1);
insert into associations values (1, 2);
insert into associations values (1, 3);
insert into associations values (2, 4);
insert into associations values (2, 5);
insert into associations values (3, 6);
insert into associations values (3, 7);
```

Then you can retrieve items for all categories:

```
select cat, name from cats inner join associations using(id) inner join items using (iid);
```

Output:

```
cat          name
-----------  ----------
soup         tomato
soup         sour
soup         corn
namkeen      katchori
namkeen      aloo
stall        tikija
stall        patties
```

Or for more compact output:

```
select cat, group_concat(name, ', ') 
from cats inner join
     associations using(id) inner join 
     items using (iid)
group by cat
order by id;
```

Output:

```
cat          group_concat(name, ', ')
-----------  ------------------------
soup         tomato, sour, corn
namkeen      katchori, aloo
stall        tikija, patties
```

I am not sure what you mean by "recycle view", maybe because I am working within pure SQLite (no other language, like you obviously use).
I hope one of the two representations suits you - or gets you on the way to achieve your goal.

MCVE foundation
(I did a `.dump` on my test environment, which I roughly cobbled together to demonstrate the idea. Please consider doing something like this for your next question involving SQLite. That makes it easier for the answerer and thereby faster for you. It also probably gets you a tighter fit of solution and often prevents misunderstandings.
Read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) if you like.):

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE table_1 (a int, b int, c int);
INSERT INTO table_1(a,b,c) VALUES(1,5,7);
INSERT INTO table_1(a,b,c) VALUES(2,10,14);
CREATE TABLE table_2 (a int, c int);
INSERT INTO table_2(a,c) VALUES(3,11);
INSERT INTO table_2(a,c) VALUES(6,22);
CREATE TABLE cats (id int, cat varchar(20));
INSERT INTO cats(id,cat) VALUES(1,'soup');
INSERT INTO cats(id,cat) VALUES(2,'namkeen');
INSERT INTO cats(id,cat) VALUES(3,'stall');
CREATE TABLE items (iid int, name varchar(20));
INSERT INTO items(iid,name) VALUES(1,'tomato');
INSERT INTO items(iid,name) VALUES(2,'sour');
INSERT INTO items(iid,name) VALUES(3,'corn');
INSERT INTO items(iid,name) VALUES(4,'katchori');
INSERT INTO items(iid,name) VALUES(5,'aloo');
INSERT INTO items(iid,name) VALUES(6,'tikija');
INSERT INTO items(iid,name) VALUES(7,'patties');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: i understood your concept. can you please help me another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612785/showing-null-pointer-exception-while-scrolling-the-recycle-view

Comment: Let's see, I would love to.